# C Algorithm and code feedback and suggestions

Tags: c, algorithm

I've put together an algorithm for an assignment. I've done my best to try and keep it to a professional and readable standard. I'm posting it here so that I can get some feedback and suggestions on what it's like and whether I could improve the algorithm in some way.

```
  /***** Algorithm 

    Comments -  Name: Shivan Kamal
                Purpose: To create a C program which takes 3 integers and produces a result that shows which triangle(If valid) they have chosen.*****/



Variable Declaration: sideA =  integer
Variable Declaration: sideB =  integer
Variable Declaration: sideC =  integer
Character Declaration = ch              

    PRINT -- " Lets explore triangles! Please insert a value for side A of your triangle \n"
    PRINT -- " Ranging from 1-15cm"

    PRINT -- " Now insert a value for side B of your triangle ranging from 1-15cm.\n"
    INPUT -- sideB

    PRINT -- "And finally, insert a value for side C of your triangle ranging from 1-15cm.\n"
    INPUT -- sideC

    IF (sideA || sideB || sideC <=0)
        PRINT "  You cannot have a triangle with any side having a value of 0.\n"
    ELSE
        IF(sideA || sideB || sideC >15) THEN
            PRINT " Please insert a value between 1cm - 15cm only."
        ELSE
            IF (sideA AND sideB == sideC OR sideB AND sideC == sideA OR sideC AND sideA == side C ) THEN
                PRINT "Your input creates a valid EQUILATERAL triangle.\n"
            ELSE
                IF (sideA==sideB OR sideB==sideC OR sideC==sideA )
                    PRINT " Your input creates a valid SCALENE triangle.\n"
                ELSE
                    IF
                        PRINT " Your input creates a valid ISOSCELES triangle.\n"
                    ELSE
                        PRINT " You have inserted invalid range of values, as a result your triangle is Invalid.\n"
                        PRINT " Please restart the program by running it again and insert valid values in order to check what triangle you would get. Goodbye."
                    ENDIF
                ENDIF
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
END PROGRAM
```

You may notice I did a char declaration but didn't use it in the rest of the algorithm. That is because I'm trying to expand on the algorithm and testing conditions. One of the things I want to do is insert a loop condition where unless a user insert a valid integer the user will be prompted to insert a valid integer, once it's inserted, the program continues on. This happens on 3 occasions at the beginning.

Also I have made the integer between a range of specific numbers. How would I be able to improve upon the algorithm so that a user can insert any number, and one of the conditions upon that is that one side of a triangle cannot be longer than the other two sides otherwise the triangle is invalid.

If a user inserts for example

sideA as = 10
sideB as = 20
 then sideC cannot be more than 30. Likewise the condition to be where SideA cannot be more than sideB and sideC combined, as well as sideC and sideA not been higher than sideB.

In my code I've currently got it set to make sure a user can only insert a valid integer, and thus will not allow a user to insert any character except an integer.

At the end of the algorithm and also in the code, i've got a ELSE-IF statement in case the user inserts anything invalid. But since I am trying to make it error proof from the beginning, what would I have to add so that I can remove the final ELSE-IF statement.

And finally I want to add a section to the algorithm where the result is "After user has got answer, the user is then asked to either try again or simply exit.

The code is pasted below if you wish to compile, check it out and make some suggestions based on what I'm trying to make the program do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    /*** Declaring triangle variable sides ****/

  int sideA;
  int sideB;
  int sideC;
  char ch;

  printf("Lets explore triangles! Please insert a value for side 'A' of your triangle.\n");
  printf(" Ranging from 1-15cm.\n");
  while(scanf("%d", &sideA) != 1)
  {
    printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number ranging between 1-15cm, and try again.\n");
    while ( (ch=getchar()) != '\n' );
  }

  printf(" Now insert a value for side 'B' of your triangle ranging from 1-15cm.\n");
  while(scanf("%d", &sideB) != 1 )
  {
    printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number ranging from 1-15cm, and try again.\n");
    while ( (ch=getchar()) != '\n' );
  }

  printf(" And finally, insert a value for side C of your triangle ranging from 1-15cm.\n");
  while(scanf("%d", &sideC) != 1 )
  {
    printf("You inserted an incorrect value. Please insert a number ranging from 1-15cm, and try again.\n");
    while ( (ch=getchar()) != '\n' );
  }

  /*** List of conditions based on user input to identify if the triangle is valid and if so, what type of triangle they get***/

  if(sideA <=0 || sideB<=0 || sideC <=0)
  {
      printf(" You cannot have a triangle with any side having a value of 0.\n");
  }
  else
      if(sideA>15 || sideB>15 || sideC >15)
      {
          printf("Please insert a value between 1cm-15cm only\n.");
      }
      else
          if( (sideA==sideC && sideB==sideC) || (sideB==sideA && sideC==sideA) || (sideC==sideB && sideA==sideB) ) /*** Code to determine EQUILATERAL TRIANGLE***/
          {
              printf(" Your input creates a valid EQUILATERAL triangle.\n");
          }
          else
              if( (sideA == sideB) || (sideB == sideC) || (sideC == sideA) )/*** Code to determine ISOSCELES TRIANGLE***/
              {
                  printf("Your input creates a valid ISOSCELES triangle.\n");
              }
              else
                  if( (sideA!= sideB) && (sideB != sideC) )/*** Code to determine SCALENE triangle ***/
                  {
                     printf("Your input creates a valid SCALENE triangle.\n");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      printf("You have inserted invalid range of values, as a result your triangle is invalid.\n");
                      printf("Please restart the program by closing it and opening it again to retry\n.");
                      printf("Goodbye.\n");
                  }
return(0);
}
```

NOTE: You may find there are some-things in the code that are not in the algorithm, this is purely because I'm a little unsure on how abouts would I write them so that it makes sense to a programmer when they try to write this program.

Comment: This belongs to [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, apologies I didn't quite know that section of the website existed. Is there any chance an admin can migrate this thread or do I have to re-write this in that thread suggested by @amit

Comment: So, no problem with code? Just to read and give feedback? O.K. : make more comments in the code. In ideal situation you will have no separate "Algorithm explanation" - all explanation will be in the comments to code

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sir, any comments on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164091/print-a-monthly-calendar-by-taking-month-and-year-as-input-using-c#comment46547784_29164091)? :-)

Comment: Thanks VolAnd. There are a few things I want to do with the code and update the algorithm accordingly. But since this is off topic, I have posted this in the section as @amit suggested. Sorry for the trouble guys

Comment: @SouravGhosh If the program works and the OP only want a review or suggestions (which seems to be the case), then yes it should be closed. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I also had the same point of view thus voted to close  with a similar reason but it seems there is some _issue_ with the reason in case of the linked question. Not very sure though. Maybe i'll add one more sentence to the earlier reason having "too broad, too" phrases now onwards. That should be ok, isn't it? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. After reading my question,  it does seem a little off topic, but in fact there are a few things within the scope that I did require a bit of input from. For example I asked how a person would try and write a while loop statement in an algorithm based on what you can see in the code. Also where and what exactly would you write in order to make this program loop itself based on user input. Example after a result is given, a few seconds later it will prompt if user wants to retry for different results or simply exit the program

Answer (score 2):

I noticed there are many if-else statement in your code so I think maybe Table-Driven Approach is an easier way to implement this logic.

```
#after range checking

CHAR *result[4] = {"a SCALENE triangle", "a ISOSCELES triangle", "Invalid", "a EQUILATERAL triangle"};
int a = sideA==sideB;
int b = sideB==sideC;
int c = sideC==sideA;
printf("Your input is %s",result[a+b+c]);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I can see what you have done there and that in fact would make a lot of sense in terms of logic. I've put my code into nested if else for mean time untill I can make improvements upon it. Your idea is rather interesting. I'll check up on it and see whether it will work for me.

Comment: btw, it doesn't reduce time complexity, and program may be slower.  cause 1. you still have to do the comparison for all sides 2. there will be no branch prediction in this case

Comment: Thanks for that, i'll keep that in mind. I like the simplicity behind it, so if I see a scenario where I can test and implement it, this method would definitely come in useful. Thanks for the feedback :D